# his use of HttpServletResponse.setHeader(...) might be used to include CRLF characters

Tags: findbugs

We have below statement in java code:

```
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

Due to this, findbugs is generating below warning:

```
 [INFO] This use of HttpServletResponse.setHeader(...) might be used to include CRLF characters into HTTP headers HTTP_RESPONSE_SPLITTING
```

Is there any way to fix this warning?

Comment: is fileName a request parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above issue is resolved by using below function:

```
private String safeHttpHeader(String value) {
    String result = "";
    if (value != null) {
        char[] chars = value.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(chars.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            switch (chars[i]) {
            case '\r':
                buffer.append('%');
                buffer.append('0');
                buffer.append('D');
                break;
            case '\n':
                buffer.append('%');
                buffer.append('0');
                buffer.append('A');
                break;
            default:
                buffer.append(chars[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
        result = buffer.toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Statement**

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", safeHttpHeader("attachment; filename=\"" + dbFile.getFilename() + "\""));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [URI(String scheme, String ssp, String fragment)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) constructor to encode the file name then extract the [raw Scheme-Specific part](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getRawSchemeSpecificPart--).

For example:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
    + new URI("http", fileName, null).getRawSchemeSpecificPart() + "\"");
```

Here is a sample program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URI uri = new URI("http", "\r\n", null);
    System.out.println(uri.getRawSchemeSpecificPart());
}
```

Which will output:

```
%0D%0A
```